# Uninstall oracle 11g enterprise edition via deleting registry keys

Tags: database, oracle

I have removed the oracle by deleting all oracle registry entries and i restart the machine and came to delete the oracle installation files directory. 
I forget to run the uninstall bat file but i assume deleting everything from registry would also enough for successfully unstallation of oracle right?

But I can not delete the oracle file folder because it keep saying need admin permission. But the login user currently has the full control. Any way if i install again oracle 11g, having this folder would not have any harm right?

Comment: I guess not. I've had several oracle homes on the same machine. make sure the new folder is the first one on the PATH local variable.

Comment: Even as an admin you are not allowed to delete everything. But you can change the permissions of that directory in order to be able to delete it. Alternatively you can take the ownership of that directory and then you will be able to delete it as well.

Comment: This is an unreliable method of deleting the product because you don't know which keys and files belong to it. It might have registered itself in other places. Also as a service.